Cant parse username with space in wazuh regex
i'm trying to use regex in a custom decoder in wazuh, but i'm stuck.
The goal is to parse the username in : [username: heyitsme].
I have this regex : [username:\s+(\S+)] that works for normal usage, even if a user tries to connect with spaces before it's username, but fails if user tries with spaces after it's username.
I tried [username:\s+(\S+)\s*] as i understood from their doc that it would work, but it seems i'm missing something.
Do you know why it fails and how can I make it work ?

\s matches only an ASCII space (32), not other whitespace like tab - maybe you want [ \t]* instead? What syntax are you using in the "code"? Try adding type=pcre2?

In regex, [ is special, escape it.

@WiktorStribiżew i tried adding type=pcre2 but it didn't change anything.
When i try escaping [ i get an error "Syntax error on regex"

The solution was to escape both [ and ], and to add type=pcre2 in the xml tag. Thanks Wiktor for your helpful comments.
The final regex in the decoder is <regex type="pcre2">for '\[username:\s+(\S+)\s*\]' from</regex>
